# Android - Sorting TextView with another Java class

Tags: java, android, sorting, textview

I want to sort some **TextView**s in an activity abstracting a Class that i've already made in which there's my sorting method, then the result of the sorting has to be written inside a new TextView.

**EDIT:**
The content of my TextViews are numbers, now i want to sort these numbers and the result of this sorting has to be written inside a new TextView.

For example :

TextView1 content : 23

TextView2 content : 41

TextView3 content : 3

**TextView4 (that will contain the rules of sorting)  : 3, 23, 41**

Comment: Sorry , Is your need is to sort the text within textView or to rearrange your textView

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please try to add more details.

Comment: Please paste your code here. Are you using list Array for sorting the text view. what you want to arrange the text in textview ?its wiered question

Comment: I have some TextView that i want to sort, the result of this sorting has to be written inside a new TextView, I hope to have been clear

Comment: You must sort not textView's but integers inside. Use textView.getText(), Integer.parseInt(), ArrayList for storing values of textViews and Collections.sort().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly this should work for you:

```
List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
data.add(Integer.parseInt(TextView1.getText().toString()));
data.add(Integer.parseInt(TextView2.getText().toString())); 
data.add(Integer.parseInt(TextView3.getText().toString()));
Collections.sort(data);
TextView4.setText(data.toString());
```